# Вывод значения ключей в названии которых присутствует строка (LocalStorage)

Tags: jquery, localstorage, key, javascript

Допустим в LocalStorage храниться вот такие ключ/значение:

```
key1/'key1'
key2/'key2'
key3/'key3'
key4/'key4'
```

А может быть и такое:

```
key1/'key1'
key10/'key10'
key4/'key4'
key32/'key32'
```

И их количество неизвестно, но известны буквы на которые начинается название ключа (в данном случае key). Как вывести значения ключей у которых в названии присутствует эти буквы (в данном случае key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = {};
for (var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){
  var key = localStorage.key(i);
  key.substr(0,3) == 'key' && (res[key] = localStorage.getItem(key));
}
console.log(res)
```